Cannot connect on port, but can ping
I am running an nginx server on docker in my Windows host using the command docker run --rm --name nginx -d -p 8080:80 nginx
I am connected to a VirtualBox Ubuntu DHCP server using a bridged adapter.
On my host, I can view the page hosted by the nginx server at http://192.168.2.50:8080/. However when I try to access the same page from inside my Ubuntu virtual machine, it eventually results in the connection timing out. I have tried using different ports as well as hosting a server on my host machine.
I have confirmed that the Ubuntu VM can ping the host's 192.168.2.50 address.
Both the host and virtual machine have another network interface that gets a 10.0.x.x IP address. the VM can connect to the nginx server using that address.
